# Using a color vector in a multipanel xyplot in r

Tags: r, colors, legend, lattice

Given 4 vectors of equal length (x,y,z,q) where q is a character vector with color names used as a grouping structure, 
I run the xyplot command:

```
xyplot(y~x|factor(z),pch=19,data=mydata,col=mydata$q)
```

Everything works fine, except that past the first factor level of z, the plots are not respecting the order of color vector q and points are randomly assigned colors from the color vector q. If I call vector q, I see that color names are correctly ordered for every level of z.

As a clear example:
a row in the data frame may contain the following values for (x,y,z,q): (13,25,march,"blue")

For the "march" plot in the multipanel xyplot, this data point will appear but as a different color, albeit a color from vector q.

I have a similar problem with using a vector with a grouping structure for cex; the first factor level produces the correct plot, but the other factor levels do not change according to the vector witha grouping structure.

If this question is not clear I will happily modify it until it makes sense. I'm sure other people are having this problem.

```
 str(cohort)



 $ date                 : Date, format: "2012-03-05" "2012-03-05" ...
 $ area                 : int  1111 3053 3555 3556 4228 6447 1111 ...
 $ score             : num  0.2282 0.1498 0.1823 0.0995 0.3083 ...
 $ color                 : chr  "purple" "blue" "brown" "violet" ...
 $ cex3                  : num  0.753 0.84 1.067 0.875 0.753 ...
 $ pch3                  : num  7 19 19 19 19 8 7 19 19 19 ...
$ time_spent            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
```

working command:

```
xyplot(score~time_spent|factor(date),groups=area,data=cohort,ylim=c(0,.6),panel=function(x,y,subscripts){panel.xyplot(x=x,y=y,subscripts=subscripts,pch=cohort[subscripts,"pch3"],col=cohort[subscripts,"color"],col.line="black",cex=cohort[subscripts,"cex3"])})
```

The actual grouping vector I want text for in a legend is cohort$area...
the character vector cohort$color and the vector cohort$pch3 are used as grouping structures to visually represent cohort$area in the plots...
thus, i want a color code/symbol legend for cohort$color and cohort$pch3 but text labels from cohort$area.

Example legend: purple dot-"1111"
                blue dot-"3053" etc.

Came up with working solution:

```
 xyplot(score ~ time_spent | factor(date), groups = area, data = cohort,auto.key=list(columns=10,points=TRUE,title="area"),
    par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(col = sort(unique(cohort$color)),pch=sort(unique(cohort$pch3)))),
    panel = function(x, y, subscripts = subscripts, groups = groups) {
    panel.xyplot(x = x, y = y,
    subscripts = subscripts, groups = groups,col.line="black",type=c("p","g"))})
```

Comment: Try passing only the unique colors to `col` and adding something for the `groups` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

A working example would have ensured that we address all of your cases. This simple example may not test more complex situations. EDIT to cover case offered by @BenBarnes:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 13:20, NA), y = 25, z = c(rep('march', 5),
  rep("april", 5)), color = c(c(rep(c("red", "green"), 2), "red"),
  c(rep(c("blue", "yellow"), 2), "blue")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

xyplot(y ~ x | factor(z), data = d1,
   panel = function(x, y, subscripts) {
       panel.xyplot(x = x, y = y,  
                    subscripts=subscripts, 
                    col = d1[subscripts, "color"])
   })
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I now realize that mastering panel functions is key to customizing multipanel plots.

Comment: Yes. And an important part of that mastery is understanding exactly what (and especially with what names) gets passed to those panel functions. Time spent in studying the `panel` subsection of the "Common Arguments" section in `?xyplot` will yield dividends.

Comment: any idea how to create a legend for this plot, i.e. creating text labels for the color grouping (red dot with new york, green dot with boston, etc.)? Key function is brutal for lattice.

Comment: I added a sample dataset with the command I'm using. As stated above, I need to add a legend where the color code refers to the color vector but text labels are from another vector with the same grouping structure as the color vector.

Comment: That's not really a "dataset" , only an incomplete description of one.

Comment: http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html   <-this is very similar to what I'm trying to achieve, except with 10 levels to the grouping structure instead of 5, and thus ten levels to specify in the legend. Like in this figure, I want the colors to be unique for each level of the grouping structure.

Comment: http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html  <-in fact, if you could show me how to reproduce this figure except with 10 levels to "Cylinders" (and a unique color for each level of the 10 levels of "Cylinders") I would be  all set.

Comment: figure 9.1 Default color theme

Answer (score 0):

One can change the default colors used by panel.xyplot in the presence of groups by changing the values for `trellis.par.get()$superpose.symbol$col`

Here is the data, this time with different colors for the different values of `z`.

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 13:20, NA), y = 25, z = c(rep('march', 5),
  rep("april", 5)), color = c(c(rep(c("red", "green"), 2), "red"),
  c(rep(c("blue", "yellow"), 2), "blue")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And here is the modified `xyplot` with a user-specified value for `par.settings`, taking into account the fact that the variable corresponding to the `groups` argument will be turned into a factor and thus sorted.

```
xyplot(y ~ x | factor(z), groups = color, data = d1,
   par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(col = sort(unique(d1$color)))),
   panel = function(x, y, subscripts = subscripts, groups = groups) {
       panel.xyplot(x = x, y = y,
         subscripts = subscripts, groups = groups)
   })
```

See `?panel.superpose` for details, since this is in fact the function that is being called when `!isNULL(groups)`